# Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.2

Tags: android, android-gradle

помогите пожалуйста

> ```
> Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
>     file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/common/25.2.2/common-25.2.2.pom
>     file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/common/25.2.2/common-25.2.2.jar
>     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.2/common-25.2.2.pom
>     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.2/common-25.2.2.jar
> Required by:
>     :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
> ```
>
> com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.2 > com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.2
>           :android_studio_project:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.2 >
>   com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.2 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.digitalborder.webappessentials"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: измените  `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` на 25.0.0. (или более позднюю)

Comment: не помогло снова ошибка